# How to make screen reader read a heading in a component on mount if initial focus is set to another element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

Is it possible to make a screen reader read a text (heading, span or div) on mount if focus is set to another element in the page?

I have a react app with a login page. The login page has input boxes for user name and password with initial focus set to username using autoFocus. The page has a heading too. How can I make a screen reader read the heading when it is mounted without losing focus from username?
Please see the sample codepen: [Sample app](https://codepen.io/libinpjoseph/pen/wvmxYvr).

The above sample has a login button in the initial landing page, clicking on it will load login component. I want screen reader to read the heading first without losing focus from username input. Tried `aria-live` attribute, but it is not working. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that the heading will be mounted at the same time or even earlier than the form?

Comment: Every thing will be loaded at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) is exactly what you are looking for.

[ARIA defines the abstract `structure` role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#structure), which groups the content in different contexts, so to say. [`landmark`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#landmark) falls under these, [`group`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#group) as well.

I’m not sure on which role this logic is based exactly, but screen readers announce these context changes, so when focus leaves one group and/or enters another, their roles and names are announced.

So if your heading serves as the accessible name for a structure that the auto-focussed input is part of, it should be announced.

One very appropriate structure role for forms is that of `group`, implemented by `<fieldset>`.

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('input').focus();">Login</button>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><h3>Enter Credentials</h3></legend>

    <label>Username
      <input name="username" autofocus>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

After pressing the Login button, NVDA (with Firefox or Chrome) will announce:

> Enter Credentials, grouping
> Username, edit, has autocomplete, blank

Orca with Firefox is similar, but Chromevox unfortunately does not announce the group, neither the name of a `<section>`.

Notice also `name="username"`. This is a common standard to allow browsers to autocomplete fields, important for accessibility. You could also add [`autocomplete="username"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) if you have a different name.

The outermost context inside the site would be that of the [`document`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#document). Its accessible name is the meta `<title>` of your page, which will be announced in the beginning, that’s unavoidable.